# Patterns with wildcard in the beginning is not matched in AIML

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, aiml

I am working AIML chatbot with Python Flask as User Interface. I found the problem when I put any wildcard symbol in AIML like '*' or '_' at the beginning of the pattern, that particular phase always unable to match with my pattern.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<aiml version="1.0">

<category>
<pattern>FIST</pattern>
<template>The Faculty of Information Science and Technology (FIST) is one of the major academic units in the university.
</template>
</category>

<category>
  <pattern>FIST _</pattern>
<template><srai>FIST</srai></template>
</category>  

<category>
<pattern>_ FIST</pattern>
<template>
 <srai>FIST</srai>
</template>
</category> 

</aiml>
```

The wildcard symbol only able to recognise at the back of the phase but it unable to return the result when I put the wildcard symbol at the beginning of the pattern.

This is my python code that connect with AIML database:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import aiml
from autocorrect import Speller
spell = Speller()

app = Flask(__name__)

k = aiml.Kernel()

print("Parsing aiml files")
k.bootstrap(learnFiles="./pretrained_model/learningFileList.aiml", commands="load aiml")

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/get")
def get_bot_response():
    specialWord = ['FIST', 'AI', 'BIT', 'BCS', 'BS']
    query = request.args.get('msg')
    querySplit = query.split()
    print(querySplit)

    commonElement = list(set(querySplit).intersection(specialWord))
    queryExclude = [i for i in querySplit if i not in commonElement]
    print(queryExclude)
    query = [spell(w) for w in queryExclude]
    print(query)

    for i in commonElement:
        index = querySplit.index(i)
        query.insert(index, i)
        print('The index of', i, 'in the list is:', index)  

    question = " ".join(query)
    print(question)
    response = k.respond(question)

 
    if response:
        return (str(response))
    else:
        return (str(":)"))
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port='5000')
```

Comment: For info, it's something in your interpreter that is causing the issue, as this is valid AIML and works under a different interpreter. Out of interest, what message are you sending to the bot which fails?

Comment: For example, if I send 'Tell me more above FIST', the bot will not able to recognise the pattern like "_ FIST".

Comment: Yes, that should work fine. It's definitely your interpreter.